# Microsoft.XMLHTTP documentElement is NULL

Tags: javascript, xml, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

Can someone offer some troubleshooting tips here? My `PostXML()` return value is `NULL` for a **very small** subset of data results. This works for 99.9% of usage. I think the failed data may have **special characters** perhaps, but comparing to a similar dataset, its identical and passes OK? The oXMLDoc.xml in File.asp contains a valid XML string while debugging, but its `null` when it gets back to my JS call.

Is there any known issues with what looks like a valid XML element getting trashed in the `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` object?

```
function PostXML(sXML)

{
    var oHTTPPost = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    oHTTPPost.Open("POST","File.asp", false);
    oHTTPPost.send(sXML);

    // documentElement is null???
    return oHTTPPost.responseXML.documentElement;
}
```

File.asp

```
<%
' oXMLDoc.xml contains valid XML here, but is NULL in the calling JS
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.Write oXMLDoc.xml
%>
```

Comment: @MarcB: no, the third argument to open() is false, which means sync mode. if sync can POST in IE i'm not sure; that was frowned upon by many browsers not too long ago...

Comment: ah yeah. phoo... basic debugging, see what you're really getting back from the ajax call. `console.log(oHTTPPost)`

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser to check the response and its HTTP headers

Comment: make sure the mime and char encoding on the served XML is correct. a lot of times Microsoft.XMLHTTP doesn't default to utf8

Comment: @Marc B The oHTTPPost is an [object], but the `documentElement` is null.

Comment: @ThW I used console.log for debugging, but haven't used it to check for response or headers. Not very savvy with IE's dev tools... I'll see if I can figure that out with IE. Chrome is so much easier!!

Answer (score 1):

Check the response headers. The content type needs to be `application/xml`.

XMLHttpRequest is available in current IEs. I suggest using the ActiveX only as a fallback.

You can override the content mimetype on it:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.overrideMimeType("application/xml");
...
```

This might by possible on the ActiveX object, too. But I am not sure.

Another possibility is using the DOMParser to convert a received string into an Document instance.

Comment: It looks valid. I've compared the built XML from the ASP to an example that processed fine and the structure is fine. Nothing jumps out as obvious abnormal. I think its data, but not sure what in the data would kill the XML in javascript. Would an ampersand (&) in the attributes cause issues?

Comment: Yes, ampersands in XML need to be encoded as `&amp;`. Not only in attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

Using IE Dev/Debugger, I found `xEFxBFxBF` in one of the string attributes. This product uses MS SQL Server and the query output did not reflect these characters even if copy/pasted into Notepad++. I'm assuming Ent Manager filters out unsupported characters... /=

Thanks for the help people!

Answer (score -1):

Ouch man.

Is it possible to use jQuery instead?

The other thing I know is that if the return xml is a little off (poorly formatted xml, case sensitive, non-legal characters) the javascript will trash the return value.

With jQuery you have better debugging options to see the error.

Comment: Naw, this is production code. It's working for the majority of calls, so its just a matter of figuring out what's different. I suspect javascript is trashing the data, but cant for the life figure out what is different.